# AngularFireAuth: Cannot read property 'GoogleAuthProvider' of undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to do authentication with AngularFire. During `ng serve`, any attempt to instantiate an auth provider (such as `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider`) results in a crash. I'm doing the exact same thing as the [AngularFireAuth quickstart example](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md). Am I missing something?

My app is quite minimal:

```
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
}
```

```
// app.module.ts

import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
// package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0-rc.2",
    "firebase": "7.14.3",
    ...
  },
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995886/how-to-fix-cannot-read-property-googleauthprovider-of-undefined) with a similar problem, but they're not using AngularFire, just plain Firebase. With AngularFire I don't think I'm supposed to manually include the Firebase scripts in my index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the real solution. `"angular-auth-firebase"` must be passed to `initializeApp()` when importing the AngularFire module in the app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, "angular-auth-firebase"),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

#### Old answer (workaround):

I have found a workaround [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2390#issuecomment-612443973). If I simply add `import "firebase/auth";` to app.module.ts, everything works, though I'm not sure this should be the permanent fix.